# org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.GeoCommand

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using aggregation as following :

```
    final List<AggregationOperation> aggregations = new ArrayList<>();
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(new Point(-26.28125, 42.19231862526141), new Point(100.28125, 64.7157757187955),
            new Point(100.28125, 42.19231862526141), new Point(-26.28125, 64.7157757187955));
    AggregationOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("location").within(polygon));
    aggregationOperations.add(match);
    aggregations.add(project("_id", "location","distance",User.COLLECTION_NAME)
            .and("$geoHash").substring(0,slice).as("geo"));
    aggregations.add(group("geo").count().as("count")
            .avg("location.lng").as("lon")
            .avg("location.lat").as("lat")
            .first(User.COLLECTION_NAME).as(User.COLLECTION_NAME));
    final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(aggregations);
    AggregationResults<ClusteredLocation> groupResults =
            mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, UserLocation.COLLECTION_NAME, ClusteredLocation.class);
    return groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

Aggregation which is being created is as follows: 
{ "aggregate" : "**collection**", "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "location" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$java" : org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.GeoCommand@d502fd15 } } } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "users", "localField" : "_id", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "users" } }, { "$project" : { "_id" : 1, "location" : 1, "distance" : 1, "users" : 1, "geo" : { "$substr" : ["$geoHash", 0, 3] } } }, { "$group" : { "_id" : "$geo", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }, "lon" : { "$avg" : "$location.lng" }, "lat" : { "$avg" : "$location.lat" }, "users" : { "$first" : "$users" } } } ] }

Exception I am getting as follows:

org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.GeoCommand.

Am I doing anything wrong in match operation?

Comment: This pretty much looks like a bug. As it seems the `Criteria` is not run through the `QueryMapper` passing a non MongoDB simple type to the driver. I've created [DATAMONGO-1986](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1986) to investigate what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround the issue by using a `TypedAggregation` or by explicitly providing an input type. Both strategies enforce the query mapping within the template.

```java
TypedAggregation agg = newAggregation(UserLocation.class, aggregations);
mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, COLLECTION_NAME, ClusteredLocation.class);

// or

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(aggregations);
mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, UserLocation.class, COLLECTION_NAME, ClusteredLocation.class);
```